# MongoDB: aggregate and group by splitting the id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My schema implementation is influenced from this tutorial [on official mongo site](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework)

```
{  
  _id: String,
  data:[
        {
         point_1: Number,
         ts: Date
        }
  ]
}
```

This is basically schema designed for time series data and I store data for each hour per device in an array in a single document. I create `_id` field combining device id which is sending the data and time. For example if a device having id `xyz1234` sends a data at `2018-09-11 12:30:00` then my `_id` field becomes `xyz1234:2018091112`.

I create new doc if the document for that hour for that device doesn't exist otherwise I just push my data to the `data` array.

```
client.db('iot')
.collection('iotdata')
.update({_id:id},{$push:{data:{point_1,ts:date}}},{upsert:true});
```

Now I am facing problem while doing aggregation. I am trying to get these types of values

- Min `point_1` value for many devices in last 24 hours by grouping on device id
- Max `point_1` value for many devices in last 24 hours by grouping on device id
- Average `point_1` for many devices in last 24 hours by grouping on device id

I thought this is very simple aggregation then I realized device id is not direct but mixed with time data so it's not so direct to group data by device id. How can I split the _id and group based on device id? I tried my level best to write the question as clearly as possible so please ask questions in comments if any part of the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on data to get single document per entry. Then you can get `deviceId` using [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/index.html) and [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/index.html) operators. Then you can apply your filtering condition (last `24` hours) and use `$group` to get `min`, `max` and `avg`

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            point_1: "$data.point_1",
            deviceId: { $substr: [ "$_id", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$_id", ":" ] } ] },
            dateTime: "$data.ts"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            dateTime: { $gte: ISODate("2018-09-10T12:00:00Z") }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$deviceId",
            min: { $min: "$point_1" },
            max: { $max: "$point_1" },
            avg: { $avg: "$point_1" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: That's so cool.  This part is `{ $substr: [ "$_id", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$_id", ":" ] } ] }` so new to me. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Currently to find which device has the lowest `point_1` I am using simple javascript code on the result of the above query but  is there any way to add changes to the above query so that it also returns lowest of all?

Comment: The easiest way would be just to sort them like `{ $sort: { "min": 1} }` otherwise you'd have to deal with `$facet` which may complicate this pipeline

Comment: `sort` works for me. Thank you. I can not use `facet` as I use 3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query in 3.6.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "deviceandtime":{"$split":["$_id", ":"]},
    "minpoint":{"$min":"$data.point_1"},
    "maxpoint":{"$min":"$data.point_1"},
    "sumpoint":{"$sum":"$data.point_1"},
    "count":{"$size":"$data.point_1"}
  }},
  {"$match":{"$expr":{"$gte":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$deviceandtime",1]},"2018-09-10 00:00:00"]}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"$arrayElemAt":["$deviceandtime",0]},
    "minpoint":{"$min":"$minpoint"},
    "maxpoint":{"$max":"$maxpoint"},
    "sumpoint":{"$sum":"$sumpoint"},
    "countpoint":{"$sum":"$count"}
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "minpoint":1,
    "maxpoint":1,
    "avgpoint":{"$divide":["$sumpoint","$countpoint"]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: I guess this is stopping from getting any value `{"$match":{"$expr":{"$gte":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$deviceandtime",1]},"2018-09-10 00:00:00"]}}},`     my id is in this format `xyz1234:2018091112`

Comment: You can try `{"$match":{"$expr":{"$gte":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$deviceandtime",1]},"2018091000"]}}}`

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention my db is `3.2` and I guess `match` part doesn't work. But your query looks interesting because there is no unwind and you are using my _id very cleverly. I tried the query from you and mickl without time limit(without match expression) and your query took 2.1s and mickl's took 3.8s. Is this because of unwind?

Comment: No worries. Yeah. Would you able to store the device id and date( as date type ) in two separate fields ? one that is better way to store the data and other I can use 3.2 aggregation pipeline and you can use $match effectively and add an index too.

Comment: I am using _id like this after watching the linked tutorial. If I create separate field for device id and hour only time stamp then I have to create an index on both of them and in an "iot environment data storage" creating index is very costly. I am supposed use _id this field very smartly but I am not able tackle that.

Comment: Sooner than later you will need index and your index performance probably will be okay if you purge/archive the data periodically. Depending on the amount of data you keep you may not even need an index.